# Enable vendor-disabled hardware on tablet?

Tags: ram, computers

I have a nextbook tablet (one of those cheap things from walmart) that I was looking to try to improve the RAM situation on to breath some new life into it as it apparently only has 1G of it. I checked the hardware readout on Linux and it reported one slot as unused, so I was sort of hoping it would be using SODIMM's and make my life easy, but alas, it was not to be with the memory soldered to the board. However, from what I found (pictured below), it actually looks like the tablet has 8GB of memory installed to it (my research says the two Nanya1429 chips on the right are [each 4G modules](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1145494/NANYA/NT5CC256M16CP-DI.html)), leading me to conclude it's one of those situations where the manufacturer just uses one hardware platform for a model series and disables some of the hardware for the cheaper models. I'm actually not entirely sure how this is usually done (maybe physically disabled? maybe BIOS?), but was wondering if anyone has any insight/experience into accessing and using such disabled hardware? 1G of memory in todays modern desktop OS's renders this largely useless (I have Fedora installed and running, but I needed to give it a ton of swap space just to keep it from oom-killing itself lol).

Appreciate the help!
[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Each of those modules is 4Gb (Gigabit). So you have 8Gb of RAM.

A byte is typically 8-bits, so that equates to 1GB of RAM, which is what your OS is reporting. There is no disabled memory that you can enable unfortunately.

The only way to upgrade would be to physically desolder the ICs and replace with a larger memory array, but that would only work if the PCB was wired for it (e.g. has unused address lines wired up). In practice it probably wouldn't work.

---

Just for the sake of interest, based on the size of the package, they are the `256M x 16` organisation, which would make sense. Two of them together would form a `256M x 32` memory arrangement, so 256M 32-bit words, which is what you would expect for a 32-bit processor with 1GB of RAM.

Comment: OMG, you're completely right. I missed those modules were measured in bits, not bytes. This is such a silly question now. Thank you

Comment: Also, thank you for the expanded explanation. Very much appreciated!

Comment: I would have been very surprised if they’d soldered the RAM chip only to disable it somehow. RAM is relatively expensive.

Comment: Typo: "same of interest" => "sake ..." (not enough rep to edit myself without bothering reviewers)

Comment: @PeterCordes good spot